# Add one prefix and sending text to telegram bot fails

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram-bot

````
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TOKEN = '......'
chat_id = '.......'

nparr = np.array(['a','b'])

message = ''    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[45, 88, 56, 15, 71], 
                'Name':['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia'], 
                'Age':[14, 25, 55, 8, 21]}) 
message = df2.to_string(index=False, header=False)
message = f'```\n{message}```'  # to keep table pretty when reached telegram
message = np.array2string(nparr) +  'some\n' + message
# message = 'for testing_' + message
message = message + '\ntime:....' 

url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}&parse_mode=Markdown"
response = requests.get(url)
print(message)
````

While sending text to telegram bot, I can add prefix string and suffix string to the message, all works, until I add a specific prefix string to the message, and it's not sent.

I purposely wrote the above test code which is simplified and contains all I need to use in real case - numpy array to string, dataframe to string, keeping table format pretty when reached telegram, etc. This test code works (sending to both terminal and telegram), but if I uncomment line 18 (add prefix 'for testing_' to message), it still can print to terminal, just can not send to telegram (no error).

Could anybody please help me find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but if I uncomment line 18 (add prefix 'for testing_' to message), it still can print to terminal, just can not send to telegram (no error).

You're adding `'for testing_' + message` to the message, but the `_` is a reserved character for the [MarkDown syntax](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style), so Telegram won't be able to decode that and throws an error.

---

> just can not send to telegram **(no error)**.

You are not printing the result Telegram is sending your, add the following:

```py
print(response.json())
```

With line 18 enabled, it shows:

```json
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 400,
  "description": "Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 11"
}
```

---

So to prevent this, use another parse_mode, or ensure that the Markdown entity is closed, eg

```
'for _testing_' + message
```

Comment: Much appreciated, "_" is the culprit!